# Excel Connection Issue in SSIS

Tags: excel, excel-2003, ssis

I have SSIS package which pulls the data from Excel(.xls) file and load the same into a SQL table. Durign design time, I am able to map the source Excel file properly and able to run the package.. But, When I replace the source file with anyother excel file in the directory location with the same name(which has same format as before), the connection fails..

I found the cause of this issue as: the Excel file which I am using has been converted from CSV or txt(I am not sure how do they convert it).. When I open those excel file it says, 'some data might be lost'-- what I need to do to run the package with this file is - Need to open the Sheet --> Click OK on the error message --> and save the file.. Now everything looks fine in SSIS connection and able to fetch the data..

I am really concerned on how do I maintain this package when deployed.. The source file needs to be opened , bypassing the error and saved everytime before initializing the connection ? Is there anyway of implementing this in SSIS.. ?

Thanks in advance..

If I am not clear in the above question.. let me know..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have faced simillar the problem with the excel file. This kind of file are generated from thirdparty softwares/languages hence cause problems.
I suggest, try to generate the proper excel file or CSV else there is no option to solve this in SSIS.

Answer (score 0):

I can't think of an implemented way of ssis to fulfill your requirement. The thing you want to archieve is fixing this file by using excel. This is nothing an ssis package can or should do. There may be some way by using a script task to program an own solution, but i think you should do the following to protect yourself an your system:

**Get import data in proper condition!**

When facing alot of corrupt data your packages have to process, this causes your system to get more and more complex. You get unflexible and error-prone. So talk to the guys providing your import data and try doing it lean.

---